# Codeigniter form validation doesn't show errors

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a problem, my codeigniter is not displaying error messages.

When I do a `var_dump` on `$this->form_validation->run()`, it returns true if everything is completed and false if not.

Here is the code:

**Controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Logon extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('logon_model', 'logon');
      }

public function autenthicate() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Usuario', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'Senha', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE):
            #Array with data
            $data = elements(array('user', 'password'), $this->input->post());
            $data['password'] = md5($data['password']);

            #Send data to model
            if ($this->logon->do_login($data)->result()):

                $data = $this->logon->do_login($data)->result();

                $user_data = array(
                    'id' => $data['id'],
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'logged' => TRUE
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                redirect('sales');

                $this->session->set_flashdata('loginerror', 'Login failed! User or password is invalid.');
                redirect('logon');
            endif;
        else:
            $data = array(
                'title' => 'Logon',
                'screen' => 'index',
            );

            $this->load->view('index_view', $dados);
        endif;
    }

}
```

**View**

```
  <?php
                    echo form_open('logon/autenthicate');
                    echo '<div class="form-group">';
                    echo form_label("User");
                    echo form_input(array('name' => 'user', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="form-group">';
                    echo form_label("passwor");
                    echo form_password(array('name' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="form-group">';
                    echo form_submit('logon', 'Logon', 'class="btn btn-default btn-block"');
                    echo '</div>';

                    #Show a alert div with validation errors
                    echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>', '</div>');
                    echo form_close();
                    ?>
```

Apparently it's all right, but I can not find the error. If the form is completed and the registered user, it will be redirected to the home page, if not back to the login screen, but without displaying the error.

Can you help me?

Comment: why do you have two redirects inside the second IF statement? Also, the last load->view('index_view', $dados);. Shouldn't that be `$data` instead of `$dados`?

Comment: Yes, is $data instead of $dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change** this to (***Best Practices***)

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
```

this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

> **Since you haven’t told the Form Validation class to validate anything yet, it returns FALSE (boolean false) by default. `The run()` method only returns TRUE if it has successfully applied your rules without any of them failing.**

[Check Why](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#try-it)

---

**Add this in controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>', '</div>');
```

and **remove this**

```
echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>', '</div>');
```

[Check Why](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters)

---

**Add this in form below the respective input fields**

```
echo form_error('usuario');
echo form_error('senha');
```

Or add

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

[Check Why](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually)

---

[CodeIgniter Form Validation Example](https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)